# Visual Basic Validating Textbox input

Tags: vb.net, validation, input, textbox

I'm having some trouble validating user input in my text boxes and I haven't been able to find a solution.

Basically, the program is a BMI calculator and i'm trying to validate user input for "gender", "height" and "weight" when the user selects the "calculate" button. Below is the the code I have so far:

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button5.Click
    Dim userBMI As BMI
    userBMI.gender = TextBox1.Text
    userBMI.height = TextBox2.Text
    userBMI.weight = TextBox3.Text
    calculatedBMI = (userBMI.weight / userBMI.height) / userBMI.height
    calculatedBmiLbl.Text = calculatedBMI.ToString("n1")
End Sub
```

The reason I need to validate these inputs is because for example, if the user inputs a string or nothing at all for the "height" input, the calculation will not work and therefore the program will break. I have thought about using some form of Boolean variable with a loop to fix this however, I am not very knowledgeable on how to do this.

If anyone could lend me some help that would be great, and it doesn't necessarily have to be a Boolean value if anyone knows an easier way to achieve the input validation it's just what I was thinking about, thanks :

Comment: Use [**`Integer.TryParse()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) on all the necessary text boxes, no looping required. If one of the `TryParse()` checks returns False then you can show a MessageBox to the user, and right after that put `Return` to not execute the rest of the code.

Comment: After playing around with it some more, I think I will be able to figure it out if anyone has a method by which I can cancel the button based on some criteria like an IF statement?

Comment: Oh wow perfect lol as soon as I posted a comment yours appeared lol. Thanks Visual Vincent I appreciate it :D

Comment: No problem. It's one of the more simple solutions you can use. If anything's unclear just let me know.

Comment: Hey mate, I'm having a little bit of trouble still using the Integer.Tryparse() method. I have tried for example, "userBMI.height = Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text) but I get an error on the "TryParse" and it's telling me that "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'TryParse' accepts this number of arguements" and I can't seem to find a fix for it.

Comment: Both the IntelliSense suggestions and the documentation I linked you to shows the declaration of the method, and the documentation has some examples of it. The return value is just a Boolean indicating wether the parsing succeeded. To set an integer you must pass that variable as the second parameter. So to check if it failed you would have to do: `If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, userBMI.height) = False Then 'Do what you want when the input is not valid.`

Comment: Could you stick an input mask onto the textboxes to eliminate the need for validation, you could even go so far as using dropdowns given the limited scope of answers.

Comment: I appreciate the help guys. Still very new to programming in general if you haven't already deduced that lol you've been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Following is example of validation to check whether input is entered or not.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button5.Click
    If Len(Trim(TextBox1.Text)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Enter Gender", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        TextBox1.Focus()
    ElseIf Len(Trim(TextBox2.Text)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Enter Height", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        TextBox2.Focus()
    ElseIf Len(Trim(TextBox3.Text)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Enter Weight", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        TextBox3.Focus()
    Else
        Dim userBMI As BMI
        userBMI.gender = TextBox1.Text
        userBMI.height = TextBox2.Text
        userBMI.weight = TextBox3.Text
        calculatedBMI = (userBMI.weight / userBMI.height) / userBMI.height
        calculatedBmiLbl.Text = calculatedBMI.ToString("n1")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try IsNumeric to check the text entered is numeric value or not

```
If(IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) ANDALSO IsNumeric(TextBox3.Text))
    Dim userBMI As BMI
    userBMI.gender = TextBox1.Text
    userBMI.height = TextBox2.Text
    userBMI.weight = TextBox3.Text

    calculatedBMI = (userBMI.weight / userBMI.height) / userBMI.height
    calculatedBmiLbl.Text = calculatedBMI.ToString("n1")
Else
calculatedBmiLbl.Text = ""
END IF
```

Or use Val() method

```
If(Val(TextBox2.Text)>0 ANDALSO Val(TextBox3.Text)>0)
    Dim userBMI As BMI
    userBMI.gender = TextBox1.Text
    userBMI.height = TextBox2.Text
    userBMI.weight = TextBox3.Text

    calculatedBMI = (userBMI.weight / userBMI.height) / userBMI.height
    calculatedBmiLbl.Text = calculatedBMI.ToString("n1")
Else
calculatedBmiLbl.Text = ""
END IF
```